Nextjs error when passing prop from server component to client component
I am fetching data from database and rendering it through a client component (because it will be added useState) but it's getting error only when passing prop. i have no Idea what's going on.
'use server'

import { Exam } from '@/db/models/exam';
import { ExamPaper } from './client-exam-paper';

const ExamPage = async ({ params }) => {
  const exam = await Exam.findById(params.examId);

  // client component 
  return <ExamPaper exam={exam} />; // error
  return <ExamPaper />; // okay
};

export default ExamPage;


./client-exam-paper page is
'use client';

export function ExamPaper() {
  return <div>asdfghjk</div>;
}


Error is
Error: Maximum call stack exceeded 


async functional component is server component and it's calling a client component. you said it's not possible. why?

in a server component its possible, try with strict mode off on next config - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/reactStrictMode

@SantanuPrasadSahoo - it's not working either

Can you log 'exam' object? The object structure could generate a circular reference.

@JulioCesarCervantesMartinez exam is a simple json, no circular reference

Are there anything else included to render this page such as layout.tsx?  I reproduced a similar snippet and it worked fine.

@DaveLin yes there is infact a layout.jsx but that's at the top level, it's working when I don't send props to client unless everything is fine. but I have to. hope it will clear

In my code findById is returning a circular object. I just had to make it plain object to pass as props with .lean() method.
'use server'

import { Exam } from '@/db/models/exam';
import { ExamPaper } from './client-exam-paper';

const ExamPage = async ({ params }) => {
  const exam = await Exam.findById(params.examId).lean();   // this is the change 

  return <ExamPaper exam={exam} />;
};

export default ExamPage;


Thanks to @JulioCesarCervantesMartinez

Thnks to @JulioCesarCervantesMartinez
